# Mi codigo de VBA no muestra lo que debería de mostrar

Tags: excel, vba

Les comento, tengo un excel, en el cual tiene boletas y facturas de pagos emitidas por día, estas pueden ser emitidas varias en un mismo día, quiero que el valor de cada boleta sea sumado en una nueva fila por día, mi problema es que el codigo si llega a correr, pero no genera ninguna suma (la fila sigue vacia), por favor alguien que me ayude, espero alguna respuesta, gracias.
(les dejo el codigo)

```
Sub SumarOpGravadasPorDia()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FechaActual As Variant
    Dim TotalDia As Double

    ' Establecer la hoja de trabajo
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TABLA COMPROBANTES")

    ' Definir la última fila hasta la fila 169
    LastRow = 169

    ' Inicializar variables
    TotalDia = 0

    ' Recorrer las filas desde la primera hasta la última con datos en la columna A
    For i = 2 To LastRow ' Suponiendo que la fila 1 tiene encabezados
        ' Obtener la fecha actual
        FechaActual = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

        ' Comprobar si es una fecha válida
        If IsDate(FechaActual) Then
            ' Verificar si es una boleta
            If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Boleta" Then
                ' Sumar el monto de Op Gravadas si es la misma fecha
                If FechaActual = ws.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                    TotalDia = TotalDia + ws.Cells(i, 8).Value ' Columna H para OP. GRAVADAS
                Else
                    ' Depositar el total en la columna "Suma x Día" (Columna I)
                    ws.Cells(i - 1, 9).Value = TotalDia
                    ' Restablecer el total para el siguiente día
                    TotalDia = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
                End If
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Error en la fecha en la fila " & i
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    ' Depositar el total para la última fecha
    ws.Cells(LastRow, 9).Value = TotalDia

    MsgBox "Proceso completado. Los totales de Op Gravadas por día se han calculado y se muestran en la Columna 'Suma x Día'."

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Por qué defines `FechaActual` como `Variant`? En cualquier caso, no veo nada raro de primeras en tu código. Ejecútalo paso a paso con F8 y mira el momento exacto en el que la suma no sale como esperas.